# Invalid CORS request: JHipster registry on Azure webapp

Tags: jhipster, azure-web-app-service, azure-webapps, jhipster-registry

I am trying to deploy default Jhipster-registry  executable Jar file on Azure webapp. The applications starts and I can see the login page. However, when I put username/password and hit submit, I get error:**Invalid CORS request (403 forbidden)**

I see that `api/authenticate` service is called. I also tried to deploy default docker image on azure webapp with docker. It also gives exactly same issue.

Basically I want to deploy Jhipster microservices along with the registry on Azure webapps because I am used to it. I expect that being normal Spring boot web application, it should be possible to achieve this.

Any help is appreciated.

regards,
Venky

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying the "application-dev.yml" file.

Comment all lines related to "CORS"

```
  # CORS is only enabled by default with the "dev" profile
#  cors:
    # Allow Ionic for JHipster by default (* no longer allowed in Spring Boot 2.4+)
#    allowed-origins: 'http://localhost:8100,https://localhost:8100,http://localhost:9000,https://localhost:9000,http://localhost:4200,https://localhost:4200'
    # Enable CORS when running in GitHub Codespaces
#    allowed-origin-patterns: 'https://*.githubpreview.dev'
#    allowed-methods: '*'
#    allowed-headers: '*'
#    exposed-headers: 'Authorization,Link,X-Total-Count,X-${jhipster.clientApp.name}-alert,X-${jhipster.clientApp.name}-error,X-${jhipster.clientApp.name}-params'
#    allow-credentials: true
#    max-age: 1800
```

Or if you prefer include your deploy location in "allowed-origin-patterns:".

In my case I added gitpod.

```
allowed-origin-patterns: 'https://*.githubpreview.dev,https://*.gitpod.io'
```